# Magento oauth request isnt using Admin role

Tags: php, api, magento, oauth, roles

I'm developing an api to connect a site to a new magento store using oauth.

I'm authenticating using the `admin/oauth_authorize` route and I've managed to get an access token and secret key to request for resources, but it's not working.

I get

```
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 403, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
```

when I try to use the token.

I checked the user roles and it's set to a rest admin role I made.  I also checked the user apps and it does register that I gave authorization.

Right now I'm testing with `api/rest/products` while setting access and secret keys that I received after authorizing.

Is there something I might be missing or could someone point me out to some useful magento oauth roles usage information?

I'm using [php oauth](http://php.net/manual/en/class.oauth.php#oauth.props.debuginfo) to make the requests.

Btw, if i give access to Guest it does return product information, just in case.

Comment: Improve grammar; improve formatting so it's more readable.  Question still needs code samples or a better explanation of what steps to take to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was missing proper oauth construction when I tried to fetch the data, I just needed to add the right auth type.